# How to open multiple page more efficiently?

Tags: python, web, url, web-scraping

I was trying to web scrape some data by opening two expedia url simultaneously. But for different URL, I would like to have different departure dates and arrival dates. As you can see, the url is long, it will be very complicated to change the date by doing +/- 1 because once i change the location ,  the whole url will change as well. 
One of the alternatives is using xpath to use mouse click to change the date, instead of changing the element in the url, but that will be slower.

Anyone has other alternatives? Thank you!

> https://www.expedia.com/Flights-Search?flight-type=on&starDate=08%2F03%2F2020&mode=search&trip=multi&leg1=from%3ALondon%2C+England%2C+UK+%28LON-All+Airports%29%2Cto%3ABarcelona%2C+Spain+%28BCN-All+Airports%29%2Cdeparture%3A08%2F03%2F2020TANYT&leg2=from%3AMadrid%2C+Spain+%28MAD-All+Airports%29%2Cto%3ALondon%2C+England%2C+UK+%28LON-All+Airports%29%2Cdeparture%3A08%2F15%2F2020TANYT&passengers=children%3A0%2Cadults%3A1%2Cseniors%3A0%2Cinfantinlap%3AY#leg/811a7451a276c854b2eba3f2fcaf8468